# What's happening in regtest mode? - Wireshark analysis

Tags: regtest, p2p, network

Motivated to watch data exchange on Bitcoin Newtwork, especially on regtest, and with hints from David Harding I decided to analyse traffic on regtest with Wireshark.

I've installed and setup (I've got a list of interfaces) Wireshark and start capturing from all interfaces available and immediately run one regtest node with following connection specification:

```
...
Bound to [::]:11111
Bound to 0.0.0.0:11111
...
```

I put a `tcp.port==18444` filter [(in the style of this description)](https://www.samkear.com/networking/analyzing-bitcoin-network-traffic-wireshark) and apply.

Problem: There's no traffic shown!
**Question: What am I doing wrong and what interface should I capture from?**

Comment: There won't be any network traffic to capture unless you have at least two nodes running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regtest mode is basically for running a node in a test network where all peers have to be added manually and it is extremely easy to solve blocks. As such, there won't be any network traffic unless you start multiple nodes and connect them using the `addnode` RPC command.

Alternatively, maybe you meant to run this in `-testnet` mode instead of `-regtest` mode?

Comment: You are right. With 2 `regtest` nodes traffic is visible in fact.